# FORG0001: Cannot convert string "N" to double

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

I have XSL statement and when running it as XSL transform, getting the following error-

```
2020-06-30 18:29:24.307  INFO 23756 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
Error evaluating ($trackCountryOfOrigin = 0 or $trackCountryOfOrigin = "N" or $trackCountryOfOrigin = "") in xsl:when/@test on line 103 column 123 of WMOSToSC2020_Item.xsl:
  FORG0001: Cannot convert string "N" to double
; SystemID: file:/C:/SCPP20/scpp-sc2020-interface-migration-master@3ec266adf36/./xslt/WMOSToSC2020_Item.xsl; Line#: 103
ValidationException: Cannot convert string "N" to double
        at net.sf.saxon.type.ValidationFailure.makeException(ValidationFailure.java:392)
        at net.sf.saxon.type.ValidationFailure.asAtomic(ValidationFailure.java:417)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.UntypedNumericComparer.quickComparison(UntypedNumericComparer.java:158)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.sort.UntypedNumericComparer.quickCompare(UntypedNumericComparer.java:58)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.GeneralComparison.compare(GeneralComparison.java:829)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.GeneralComparison.evaluateManyToOne(GeneralComparison.java:704)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.GeneralComparison.effectiveBooleanValue(GeneralComparison.java:651)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.OrExpression.effectiveBooleanValue(OrExpression.java:133)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.OrExpression.effectiveBooleanValue(OrExpression.java:133)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.choose(Choose.java:917)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Choose.java:892)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:721)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:721)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:721)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:721)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.process(LetExpression.java:608)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.lambda$processLeavingTail$0(ForEach.java:484)
        at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.processLeavingTail(ForEach.java:484)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:349)
        at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:485)
        at net.sf.saxon.trans.XsltController.applyTemplates(XsltController.java:733)
        at net.sf.saxon.s9api.AbstractXsltTransformer.applyTemplatesToSource(AbstractXsltTransformer.java:348)
        at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:341)
```

**Here is my xsl Statement-**

```
<xsl:variable name="trackCountryOfOrigin" select="LotReq"/>
    <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$trackCountOfOrg=0 or $trackCountOfOrg='N' or $trackCountOfOrg=''">"trackCountOfOrg": 0,&#xa;</xsl:when></xsl:choose>
```

**Here is input xml-**

```
<LotReq>N</LotReq>
```

**Note-**
 - this tag can have N or 0 populated.
We are using Saxon processor to transform this XML using XSL.

Comment: So where do you bind which value exactly to the variable `trackCountOfOrg`? What kind of comparison you want to perform when it seems to be a double number but you want to compare it to the string `N`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please edit your original post and provide the following:
(1) Input XML 
(2) Your logic, and XSLT you tried to implement it. 
(3) Desired output.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I edited my question.

Comment: Why don't you simply change `$trackCountOfOrg=0` to `$trackCountOfOrg='0'`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, it's helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath 2.0+, the operands of "=" must be of comparable types: you get an error (as here) if one operand is a string and the other is a number. You should either convert the number to a string, or the string to a number.

That's different from XPath 1.0, which did an implicit conversion (though it's so long ago, I've forgotten the exact conversion rules).

In 2.0+ you still get implicit conversion if one of the arguments is of type xs:untypedAtomic - which in practice means, if it is a node and there is no schema. In this situation the string value of the node will be converted to the type of the other operand.